# Laravel Eloquent query with relation

Tags: relationship, one-to-many, laravel-5.7, eloquent-relationship

In a Laravel environment (v 5.7) I've two tables: **films** and **versions** related in a 1 to Many relationship defined in Models as so:

```
class Film extends Model {
    ...
    public function versions() {
        return $this->hasMany(Version::class);
    }
}
class Version extends Model {
    ...
    public function film() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Film::class);
    }
}
```

I want to pick a random Version of a Film **and its related parent Film**, so in a controller I do this:

```
...
use App\Film;
use App\Version;

class HomeController extends Controller {
    ...
    public function index() {
        $rndVersion = Version::inRandomOrder()->first();
        $relatedFilm = $rndVersion->film->first();
```

All works fine, except the fact that *the returned **film** is always the first of the entire recordset, and not the parent of the **version** I previously loaded from the DB.*

I've tried to retrieve all together with:

```
$rndVersion = Version::inRandomOrder()->with('film')->first();
```

and it works, but it packs all in a single object stored in $rndVersion, and I'd rather prefer to keep the two things separate.

So, what am I doing wrong?
What shall I generally do to get the parent record of a selected/loaded one?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue...

The way you call the relationship method defined in the Model changes the returned result.

In general, if you call:

```
$model->relationship() //with parenthesis
```

an **instance of the relationship** is returned. You are calling the method as a method and, as it is for Eloquent model classes, it "serves as powerful query builder" and "provides powerful method chaining and querying capabilities" ([see here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)).

Otherwise if you call:

```
$model->relationship //without parenthesis
```

you get directly an **instance of the Collection**. This way you are calling the method as a property and getting a [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-collections) thus letting you loop on the collection, get record (model) properties and use all the methods of the Collection class.

So, in my case, writing

```
$rndVersione = Version::inRandomOrder()->first();
$rndFilm = $rndVersione->film()->first(); //film() WITH parenthesis
```

works, I guess because the first() method is called on the relationship as a method, therefore maintaining the correctness of query building.